# Is "background" a helpful tag?

Tags: discussion, support, stack-overflow, tags

There are about 3800 questions using [background](/questions/tagged/background), where the tag is used for different purposes, such as background music, a background process, the background of an HTML page, the background of an application, an application running in the background, a background service.

Is the tag really helpful? Should be replaced with other tags, or should it be simply burninated?

Comment: I just noticed the same, although by now it's over 6000 questions. What would be a good way to start tackling this?

Comment: Replace it where it can be replaced. After that, it could be burninated, which means Stack Exchange staff can removed the tag from the question revisions, and it would be as if the tag has never been used.

Comment: Hmm, I'm mostly at home in the html/css/js area. I'll see if I can tackle a couple at a time regularly and rename them to 'html-background'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Oh, the tag should definitely be burninated, but in the process, the tag should be replaced (or new tags generated where appropriate) with something more specific.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, I think the tag needs to become more specific. [background](/questions/tagged/background) really surprised me since it seemed a bit unnecessary.

I would suggest [background-processes](/questions/tagged/background-processes), [background-music](/questions/tagged/background-music) and [html-background](/questions/tagged/html-background) perhaps as alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

Altough It would be a useful tag it's not specific enough. It's used for a lot of different purposes now. (css, music, objective-c).